# Переключение между view в рамках одного viewcontroler - а

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios7

подскажите возможно ли переключение между `View` у одного `ViewControler` ?

1. если возможно то как?
2. насколько это подходит идеологии построения приложений под `IOS`?

(необходимо сделать логин + логин через соцсети + регистрацию, хочу все сделать в 1 `ViewControler`. И если все ок загружать уже другой `ViewControler` управляющий приложением)

Comment: Это плохая практика, не делайте так.

Comment: Согласен с тем что регистрацию надо вынести на отдельный контроллер. но почему не оставить логин и вход через соцсети на одном контроллере?
так меньше есть памяти. да и есть некоторая логика 1 контролер за 1 операцию отвечает в данном случае вход. будь он через webView или напрямую через логин. 1 селектор анализирующий респонс от сервера.

Comment: Нее, вы можете делать кучу вьюшек и управлять ей одним контроллером. Но в вашем ТЗ, я бы WebView для соц сетей вынес в отдельный контроллер. Так как там будет логика чисто обрабатывающая вход. И 1 контроллер и 1 вебвьюха на каждую соц сесть. А кнопки VK,FB,TW можно оставить в главном контролере, так как там будет тупо вызов презентации контроллера с WebView.

Comment: изначально так и сделал. но уперся в то что при использовании presentViewControler без dismissViewControler жрет много памяти. А при использовании их в паре не получается переход: login->VC(WebView)->EnterToMyProject. надо сначала из VC(WebView) дисмисом вернутся на стартовый контролер и потом презентовать третий. (опять таки все из-за утечек памяти в симуляторе) Может не обращать на них внимания и надеяться на ARC и просто presentViewControler  дальше и дальше?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте разные UIViewController для контроля разных UIView - в этом и есть идеология, если необходимо - создайте базовый класс. Чтобы переключаться между экранами логина используйте UINavigationController - задача которого как раз в управлении навигацией между разными экранами.

Comment: изначально я так и сделал 1 базовый. ряд наследников. под каждый UIView свой ViewControler, но уперся в проблему перехода между ними. вариант "медиатора" хранящего указатели на каждый контролер и делающего переход типа presentViewControler и dissmisViewControler не подошел. в сториборде если накидывать связи между кнопками то начинает много жрать памяти приложение.
Ищу другие варианты как например несколько View на 1 ViewControler + TabViewControler или это тоже "плохой тон"?

Comment: почему  `вариант  presentViewControler и dissmisViewControler` не подошел?

Comment: пример:есть 3 контролера №1, 2 и 3. у каждого есть id и по id из сториборда я создаю 3 указателя типа UIViewControler .
дальше. при переходе из 1 во 2 (1->2) я делаю [self presentViewControler:vc2]; при возврате (2->1) делаю [[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControler]. на этом этапе все ок.
Проблемы начинаются после следующего перехода (1->2) и попытка перейти (2->3) если я сделаю presentViewControler то уже не могу пользоваться указателем на 1 и 2  презентовать их при дальнейшем переходе (вылет с ексепшеном) . если я сделаю дисмис и потом презент то я просто вылетаю на стартовый